# Python While loop keeps repeating

Tags: python

I am trying to use this program I created and I want the program not to repeat the option a lot of times here is the program:

```
 # A Program to show how to use a menu
 menu=int(input("What would you like? \n\
 1. A compliment \n\
 2. An insult \n\
 3. A proverb \n")) 
 y=True
 while y==True:
     if menu==1: #compliment
           print ("You look nice today")
     elif menu==2: #insult
           print("You smell")
     elif menu==3: #proverb
           print("A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush!")
     else:
          y==False
          print("Invalid option")
          break
```

What happens is that when I type in the option for example 2 the program repeats
You smell
You smell
You smell
You smell
You smell
infinite times.

Comment: `'y==False' != 'y = False'`...

Comment: Your condition never becomes false.  If you want it to break out, you could A) put in a break statement or B) add `y = False` to stop your while statement.  I'm not positive about option A because python doesn't support `break` in an `if` statement, but it _might_ (maybe) work since it is in the `while` statement.

Comment: yes, you can 'break' out of a while statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues. As @Arrjun Ram mentioned you have `y==False` when you need `y=False`

The other issue you have is that your call to `input` is outside the `while` loop. This means the value of menu will never change. You need to move it to the inside of the `while` loop.

You might also add an option, say 4, to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop never ends.  You have a break under your final 'else', but you're assuming that your variable `menu` will actually be modified.  You shouldn't be looping on the response, but instead overall as such:

```
y=True
while y==True:
    menu=int(input("What would you like? \n\
    1. A compliment \n\
    2. An insult \n\
    3. A proverb \n")) 

    if menu==1: #compliment
       print ("You look nice today")
    elif menu==2: #insult
       print("You smell")
    elif menu==3: #proverb
       print("A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush!")
    else:
       print("Invalid option ")
       y = False
```

The above will run until an invalid option is entered and then the loop will break.  Your original code would never break since `y` can never be modified.  Your `y==False` is a comparison operation, NOT an assignment operation.  However, that STILL would never be hit, because you're not asking for additional input within your loop so it would remain `TRUE` forever.